# Get column by names

Tags: pandas

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
           Date   Adj Close                   Close                    High  ...         Low                    Open                Volume           
                       AAPL         SPY        AAPL         SPY        AAPL  ...        AAPL         SPY        AAPL         SPY      AAPL        SPY
2050 2023-02-28  147.410004  396.260010  147.410004  396.260010  149.080002  ...  146.830002  396.149994  147.050003  397.230011  50547000   96438600
...
```

How do I get a `DataFrame` with just the Close of AAPL and the Close of SPY?

I tried this but I get an error:

```
column_names = ['Close' + ticker, 'Close SPY']
data = data[column_names]

raise KeyError(f"{keyarr[cmask]} not in index")
KeyError: "['CloseAAPL' 'Close SPY'] not in index"
```

Comment: Please see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4450498) and provide a reproducible way for us to ingest your DataFrame ourselves. Are those column labels a MultiIndex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure without access to your DataFrame, but my guess is that your column labels are a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html), in which case treating each column name as a single string (i.e. `"Close SPY"` will not work (even if you *did* have a space in your `'CloseAAPL'` string, which `'Close'+ticker` does not create). Instead, try `column names = [("Adj Close", ticker), ("Close", "SPY")]` or something similar.